# Is there a way in MySQL to use an "IN" like function for substrings

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am using the latest version of grafana with a MySQL backend.  Grafana allows you to create pull down variables that can be set to multiple values. This is useful when using the mySQL "IN" command like this:

```
select * from t1 where columnA IN ($grafanaVariable)
```

The grafanaVariable can be set to one or multiple values so the MySQL query can look something like this

```
select * from t1 where columnA IN ('grafanaVariable1', 'grafanaVariable2', ...)
```

I have come across a recent use case where I have a MySQL column that contains variable number of substrings.  I would like to put these substrings in a grafana variable and use a command similar to the IN command that produces similar results.

I have tried using the INSTR and POSITION commands but they will not work when the grafanaVariable is set to multiple values.  I have tried using the IN command also but that does not work for sub-strings.

working example with columnA as strings:

```
|    columnA    |    columnB    |
|    cat        |    1000       |
|    dog        |    1001       |
|    crab       |    1002       |
|    horse      |    1003       |
|    cat        |    1004       |
|    crab       |    1005       |

$grafanaVariable = distinct(columnA);
```

MySQL Query:

```
select columnB from t1 where columnA IN ($grafanaVariable)
```

user selects 'crab' and 'dog' in the grafanaVariable pulldown

Result is:

```
|    1001       |
|    1002       |
|    1005       |
```

Example with columnA as substrings:

```
|     columnA                       |    columnB    |
|    subString1subString2           |    1000       |
|    subString1subString2subString3 |    1001       |
|    subString3                     |    1002       |
|    subString2subString3           |    1003       | 
|    subString3subString4           |    1004       | 

$grafanaVariable = ('subString1', 'subString2', 'subString3');
```

user selects 'subString1' and 'subString2'

Desired Result is:

```
|    1000       |
|    1001       |
|    1003       |
```

Comment: Your data is a bit messy.  Please show clear table data, formatted as a _table_.  Note that storing CSV this way is not optimal table design.